# Is a chronological testing split required for this problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, train-test-split

I'm training a regression model (probably gradient boosting based) that has some time based features. Mainly in the form of the day, month, year and day_of_week.

Results change based on whether its a weekend or not, or if there is a public holiday in the next 5 days, etc.

Might be a very stupid question but I am not exactly sure if there can be data leaked if I use a randomized test-train split vs a chronological split.

For example, there was a process change in 2023 that influences the target variable. But the year is already a feature.

---

I'd assume it would matter if I was using truly time series features that isn't the time itself.